# how to otpimize request latencyPython Tornado service on google cloud run

Tags: python, docker, tornado, google-cloud-run

I am using Python 3.7 tornado framework to develop the HTTP POST web service and I have deployed it as Cloud Run on GCP. I am new to Python and Tornado framework. What I understand is tornado runs as a single thread web server when deployed. I have configured max instances of 12, concurrency of 30 and Memory of 1GB while deploying my service to cloud run. I still get request latency of 20-30 seconds while serving say 80 requests per second to my service. Do I need to change my application code to handle more concurrent requests or async requests in tornado apart from configuring cloud run parameters? Following is the snippet of my request handler, after receiving request I do some transformation on data and few I/O calls to GCS, BQ and pubsub from my application code.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
class EventHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        //extract request body
        // use defs to transform data
        // send to pubsub topic
        self.set_status(200, 'Ok')
        self.write(chunk='Valid Message')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = tornado.web.Application([("/", EventHandler)])
    application.listen(port=8080, address='0.0.0.0')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

How many tornado processes are started by default when I deploy the service to Cloud Run? how can make the application code to serve more concurrent request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: another thing I came to know that tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start() does os.fork internally and creates separate child processes. Is there a way to specify how many tornado subprocesses will be created when the server starts? Does that help in increasing application performance?

Comment: hello, the latency depends on many factors, from an issue in the network until a bad handling of requests in the service, what do you think could be a problem with Cloud Run? Did you check the official documentation about latency in Cloud Run?https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#latency-domains

Comment: `IOLoop.current().start()` doesn't fork multiple processes., it only runs a single process. It is `HTTPServer.start()` which does the fork. See example here: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#processes-and-ports. The latency you're seeing is probably because you're doing blocking some blocking tasks.

Comment: @xyres how can I change the code to do IO operations in the background asynchronously and send HTTP response first?

Comment: @OnkarPathak If you're sending your IO requests over HTTP, you can use Tornado's [`AsyncHTTPClient`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#module-tornado.httpclient). If you're sending requests over a different protocol, you'll need an async client for that. But what about this *"transformation on data"* operation? Is this a CPU intensive task? If so, execute it in a separate thread.

Comment: @xyres Thanks a lot. your earlier comment helped in spawning multiple processes using `HTTPServer.start()`. About "transformation on data" its not CPU intensive operation. We do some json parsing, validation and send that json event to GCS, Pubsub and BigQuery through our service. For now the performance of my app is fine. any suggestions on how can I convert this into `async def post(self)` efficiently?

Comment: @OnkarPathak Why do you want to make it `async`? If I understand you correctly, you want to return the response to the client before you send data to GCS, etc. In that case you don't need any async features. I could post an example if you like. Or did I misunderstand you?